Why does xmodmap does not work in some native Linux games?
Something that has been annoying me for a bit is that my caps:escape xmodmap option does not work in some games including Minecraft and Team Fortress 2.
When pressing the capslock/escape button, nothing happens; it triggers neither an escape key event nor letter capitalisation toggle. This is consistent across Xorg (i3) and Wayland/xwayland (Hyprland).
I can't find a determining factor that is consistent across all scenarios because it does work in Cities:Skylines. Looking at libraries/APIs used, all games use OGL, C:S and TF2 use SDL2 and the bug is present in MC eventhough it uses the LWJGL/GLFW middleware and generally has very little in common with the other two games.
What could be the cause and how can I make it use my xmodmap options?
(I'm not interested in alternatives to using xmodmap, I'm aware you could achieve a capslock remap through different means.)
